# Looking for assistance on joining queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm having trouble joining two activerecord queries together. The uncommented code displays what actually works and the commented out code displays what I thought should be the code. Obviously the commented out code needs to be in the loop.

```
$musicQuery = "album1,album2,album3,album4");

$albums = explode(",", $musicQuery);
foreach($albums as $i => $album) {

    $albumQuery = $this->db->get_where('albums', array('id' => $album), 1)->row_array();                                

    $artistQuery = $this->db->get_where('artists', array('tc_id' => $albumQuery['artist']), 1)->row_array();

    echo $artistQuery['artist'].'<br>';
}

// This is what I thought I would need
//$this->db->select('*');
//$this->db->from('albums');
//$this->db->join('artists', 'artists.id = albums.artist');
//$this->db->where('id', $album);
//$this->db->limit(1);                              
//$this->db->order_by("post_views", "desc"); 
//$artistQuery = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join query should be something like this

```
  $this->db->join('artists', 'artists.tc_id = albums.artist');
```

Unless that was an typo from your side while posting the query  here